# difference between python and node base64 decoding

Tags: python, node.js, encoding, base64

I am puzzled at this base64 decoding issue, and it seems that python and node.js does this differently. Node does this correctly I believe. Could anyone help point out why python does not work here?

Thank you.

Node

```
> console.log(Buffer.from('Im3Osc6_z4HPgc-J==', 'base64').toString());
"mαορρω
```

Python

```
>>> from base64 import decodestring
>>> print decodestring('Im3Osc6_z4HPgc-J==')
"mαγ?s?p
```

Comment: Base64 has nothing to do with this; the bytes are probably decided correctly, the problem is what character encoding has been used to prepare the bytes buffer in first place (and what python and node are using).

Comment: OK, so how to change python to get the same results then?

Comment: By decoding the string using the same codec as that which was using to encode it. How did you create that string?

Comment: @Robᵩ I am given this string as an input, no choice to change it.

Comment: OK. How did the person who gave it to you construct it?

Comment: @Robᵩ what you said doesn't make sense to me. Here, we have the same input string, clearly node and python produces two different results. There is nothing else given. Just based on these facts, it is a valid question to ask why python produced wrong results. Don't you think?

Comment: Yes, that's a valid question. The answer is "because you didn't give it enough information, and the default information it has doesn't apply to this input." The missing information has to do with how the bytes are encoded. Actually, I take that back. It is presumptuous and possibly premature to say that node.js gave the "right" answer and python gave the "wrong" answer. Without knowing how the data was encoded, we can't know for certain what the "right" answer is.

Comment: It actually does make sense; who produced that string started with some unicode characters, encoded them in some encoding and then converted the resulting byte array in base64. After decoding the base64, it's necessary to know the encoding used for the initial unicode characters to bytes conversion to decode them correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you provided is actually not a standard base64, but a URL-safe base64

> which substitutes `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/` in the standard Base64 alphabet"

To decode it in Python you need to use [`base64.urlsafe_b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64decode).

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode('Im3Osc6_z4HPgc-J==')
'"m\xce\xb1\xce\xbf\xcf\x81\xcf\x81\xcf\x89'
```

Then, the byte string that is encoded in that base64 is in UTF-8; to get a Unicode string, you have to decode it:

```
>>> print base64.urlsafe_b64decode('Im3Osc6_z4HPgc-J==').decode('utf-8')
"mαορρω
```

With `base64.decodestring` you got weird results because it just drops any character that is not part of the standard base64 alphabet, so it decoded incorrect bytes.